# Distributed data storage infrastructure for storage of video streams

Tags: distributed-system, amazon-ebs, iscsi

I'm exploring options for multi-site cluster-based distributed data storage middleware. Software like Lustre, HDFS and perhaps OpenStack Swift may be of interest. However the primary difficulty I face is that the data storage infrastructure is for a Windows-based application.

The Windows-based application writes to volumes (like database servers). Therefore, the data storage subsystem must be able to create iSCSI targets (along the lines of Amazon EBS). Commercial Vendors such as EMC, HP have proprietary solutions.

Is anyone aware of an open source solution (with a liberal license) that enables the creation of block storage on top of a distributed infrastructure (or an open source Amazon EBS clone)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at gluster ( http://www.gluster.org/ ).

This is a not so bad distributed filesystem that is seeing some adoption in openstack land.

Openstack ( openstack.org ) also has a method for creating iscsi targets inside of the nova compute controller.  It's called volume creation.  It will take an available volume group on compute nodes running the volume service and dynamically allocate LVMs inside the groups then create iscsi targets that are available to project instances inside of the cloud environment.

Hope that helps.